# Javascript redirect to two thank you pages, depending on form response

Tags: javascript, forms

There is a yes or no field on the form, depending on user's choice I would like to send them to a different thank you page depending on their answer.

With this, I just get a blank page. I've tried everything I can think of, so I appreciate any insight.

```html
<form action="http://www.google.com/form" name="Lead" id="Lead" class="sem-form"  onsubmit="return redirectTY()">
    <label class="select">
        <select name="Invest_RD" id="Invest_RD">
        <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="No">No</option>
        </select>
    </label>
</form>
```

```js
function redirectTY(){
    var qualify = document.getElementById("Invest_RD".value);
    if (qualify == "Yes"){
     window.location.href='http://www.google.com';
    } else {
     window.location.href='http://www.bing.com';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine, except for this detail:

```
document.getElementById("Invest_RD".value);
```

This will crash all your javascript. Probably your console (developer tools) have red messages refered to this. To fix it write:

```
document.getElementById("Invest_RD").value;
```

That's because `getElementById()` is a method of `document`, and `value` is a property of the element returned by `getElementById()`.

Answer (score 0):

In your code snippet you are missing the `submit button` to submit the form or any other action call that executes the button submit. When the action call is done alone the form will submit and you can check upon the values.

Hence your HTML will look like

```
<form action="" name="Lead" id="Lead" class="sem-form"  onsubmit="return redirectTY()">     
<label class="select">
<select name="Invest_RD" id="Invest_RD">
<option value="Yes">Yes</option>
<option selected="selected" value="No">No</option>
</select></label>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT" />
</form>
```

You no need an action to the since it is calling the JS after the form is submitted and you can catch up from there on.

The select tag value can be retrieved using the following JS and you can perform the calculations.

```
$('#Invest_RD').val(); // Getting the selected value from the select tag
```

Answer (score 0):

Add submit button `<input type ="submit" value="submit">` to trigger the onsubmit event in your html form. and change `onsubmit = "redirectTY();return false;"`

```
  <label class="select">
    <select name="Invest_RD" id="Invest_RD">
         <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
         <option selected="selected" value="No">No</option>
    </select></label>
   <input type ="submit" value="submit">
  </form>
```